# What is a folder.pst and how can I import or search it

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, restore, pst

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9cED.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34IHG.png)I need to find an important email. I saw it in the past few months and know its there somewhere.
Ive searched outlook and its "searched the server" it says. I dont trust it, but have to accept the answer. Not found.
I started finding my old .pst files I backed up and placed on onedrive. I was downloading and importing them.
I came across quite a few folders (showing a folder icon) with a .pst extension and when clicked, they contain .db files.
I cant find out what they are or how I might search them.
Does anybody know?

Please suspend disbelief for a minute and have a go at the actual question.
If I had this issue, so will you before long.

I rausa search in onedrive for *.pst    I wanted all my backups going back for years.  Right?

What I got contained two types of entity.
The first: A .pst file jsut as you all expected.
The second: A folder (folder icon) with a .pst extension.  Yes!  Thats exactly what it was.

I clicked this icon and it opened just like a folder does.
Inside this folder.pst were lots of files each with a .db extension.

Anyone know what this is and how to deal with them
?
Id upload two images but I'm not allowed. My old login is lost.'

Comment: .db files are not .pst files or format. You can open and search any pst file but not other formats.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question title refers to .PST files (which is the file extension for a personal Outlook Archive), but your question body, referred to an entirely different file extension not even used by Outlook.

Comment: Open the `db` files with a text editor and check visually if they contain email messages. If not, there is no point in searching them.

Comment: Clealry nobody has seen this before.
My point is that a search for *.pst brings back .pst files, but also folders (folder icon) with a .pst extension and when I click on that folder, it contains hundreds of .db files.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth:

*.PST files are created by Outlook, to store emails and probably other "PIM" Personal Information Manager?)stuff too.

In the File menu of Outlook you have options to open such files.
An open file can be searched, with Outlooks fumble search functions.

Note that if you enable the quick search (e.g. upper right of the reading pane), then the ribbon changes so that you see "Search options"; where you find a more advanced Search function - which allows to pinpoint a PST to search in.

*.db files on the other hand, I relate to Database software, the details doesn't seem to be relevant here though.

***I often find that Outlook fails to find stuff that is "in clear vicinity"; i can literally be looking at it, attempting to use the search function to selectively show only those items... and it fails!***

Comment: Note that the question says that the OP has a ***folder*** whose name ends with `.pst`.

Comment: Note that a PST file can **contain** folders. The OP has not clearly stated the actual problem. The A here *might* help.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, a PST file can be uesd to download all of your email messages from your mail server and save them on your computer, and can also be used when you want to import or export emai messages calendar, contact, and task data.
[image]

According to your description, it's suggested that you could try to import the PST file in Outlook client and check if the lost email exists. For more information about importing the PST file, please refer to: [Import email, contacts, and calendar from an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/import-email-contacts-and-calendar-from-an-outlook-pst-file-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac).

Hope to help you!

Comment: I already had tried import before raising the question. pst files import fine but sadly dont contain what I want. The pst folders foldername.pst on the other hand, can not be imported and neither can any of the .db files contained within them.
I'm not mad, this really happened.

Comment: If you still can't find the email you want after importing PST and searching in outlook, considering that this email has been deleted and cleaned up, you might as well try to recover the item deleted from the deleted folder in Outlook client(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/recover-deleted-items-in-outlook-for-windows-49e81f3c-c8f4-4426-a0b9-c0fd751d48ce#:~:text=Recover%20an%20item%20that%27s%20no%20longer%20in%20your%20Deleted%20Items%20folder) and check whether you can find the email.